# What versions of Android and iOS is Adobe AIR 3.0 captive runtime compatible with?

Tags: android, ios, flash, actionscript-3, air

I can't find this information online or in the documentation, does anyone know what versions of Android and iOS the AIR 3.0 captive runtime is compatible with? I'm assuming there is some restriction there, but short of actually compiling a program and trying it on iPhone for example, which I don't have, how can I tell which OS versions are supported?

I know that you can compile an Adobe AIR 2.7(?) application to target say Android 2.2, but what about the captive runtime with AIR 3.0? Also I don't see anywhere to find out the iOS version restriction with AIR, as you have to pay $100 to Apple to even get the SDK which would allow me to make an iOS project in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System requirements using captive runtime are the same as without - in other words, quoting from the [reqs page](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html):

- Android™ 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2
- iPod touch (3rd generation) 32 GB and 64 GB model, iPod touch 4, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPad, iPad 2
- iOS 4 and above

Incidentally, note that captive runtime is not a new option for iOS - it's how AIR has always worked there, since iOS doesn't allow using a separate runtime. So really, captive runtime is a matter of doing on Android (or elsewhere) what's been done on iOS all along.

Answer (score 2):

I would suppose captive runtime apps work on all the devices which originally support AIR. Captive runtime just packages the AIR packages (which would otherwise be separately installed) into your application so that a separate download is not required.

As for iOS, I believe the compiler creates native iOS code (because Apple will disallow all apps which run on 3rd party frameworks), so the app should work on all versions of iOS supported by your sdk.